# Unknown provider: userFactoryProvider <- userFactory <- userController

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory, angularjs-injector

Initially, I made a controller to keep the data for me and It was working for me. then I moved my data to a factory. I injected my factory to the controller. I also putting the address of my module/controller/factory in my HTML code, but I receive error of "Unknown provider"

here is my factory codes:

```
(function() {

    var userFactory = function () {

        user = 
            {
            "objectId": "NlPjdF5yK2",
            "username": "saberi.ar.eng@gmail.com",
            "emailVerified": "true",
            "email": "saberi.ar.eng@gmail.com",
            "myOwnCards": "['zIlHxyotrV','i1OOfskc9p','pv3NeClPkb','sdNuOoa7L2']", 
            "name": "Alireza",
            "profile": "Ali",
            "surname": "Saberi",
            "image": "../assests/images/people/NlPjdF5yK2.jpg"
            };

        var factory = {};
        factory.getUser = function(){
            return user;
        };

        return factory;
    };
        angular.module('ccApp').factory('userFactory', userFactory);

}());
```

and here is my controller condes

```
(function() {

    var userController = function ($scope,userFactory) {
        user = {};

        function init(){
            $scope.user = user;
        };

        init();

    };

    userController.$inject = ['$scope','userFactory'];

    angular.module('ccApp').controller('userController', userController);

}());
```

Comment: It work here: http://plnkr.co/edit/J5jdqEL5BOvu2fRRw8Ej?p=preview

Comment: what was wrong with it? Unknown provider and Injection errors are driving me crazy in AngularJS. and finding where the error is to hard.

Comment: hmm, I can find the difference between your codes and mine! :(
Except that I put the module, controller and factory in different files

Answer (score 0):

I think, here is the answer:

> The  order of dependency is important. Since you are calling user
>   factory from the controller, you need to load it before the
>   controller.